# Irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory

I just started to learn representation theory and I'm interested in the irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. I looked them up in three different books and apparently, I misunderstood something because for me, they are inconsistent statements.

> Stanley (Enumerative Combinatorics II, Theorem A2.4):
>   *The irreducible polynomial representations $\varphi^{\lambda}$ of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be indexed by partitions
>   $\lambda$ of length at most $n$.*
>
> Bump (Lie Groups, Theorem 38.3):
>   *The irreducible algebraic representations $\varphi^{\lambda}$ of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are indexed by integer sequences
>   $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$.*
>
> Fulton, Harris (Representation Theory, Proposition 15.47):
>   *Every irreducible complex representation of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\varphi^{\lambda}$
>   for a unique index $\lambda=\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ with
>   $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$.*

My questions are:

1. Is every algebraic irreducible representation indexed by a partition or by an integer sequence with $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$?
2. Can every irreducible representation be indexed by an integer partition with $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$ or only the irreducible alegbraic representations?

Comment: What values do Fulton-Harris allow for the $\lambda_i$?

Comment: I just looked up the result in Stanley, and you misquoted it slightly. It should be "polynomial" instead of "algebraic".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It says that some of the $\lambda_i$ can be negative. So, they're integers.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's true. But aren't polynomial and algebraic representations not the same thing?

Comment: No, being polynomial is stronger than being algebraic, and here it precisely amounts to whether one allows negative powers of the determinant to appear.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my first question.

Comment: For the definition of polynomial representations in this context, you can check earlier parts of the same appendix in Stanley.

Comment: I need to think a bit more about the statement from Fulton-Harris. They seem to end up showing that all irreducible representations are algebraic, but their argument lifts from the Lie algebra, and uses that the group $SL_n(\mathbb{C})\times \mathbb{C}$ is simply connected. But I think we need to assume at least that the representations are continuous (maybe even smooth) for that sort of argument.

Comment: (I may expand this into an answer later, but feel free to answer the question yourself now if you wish). Unless Fulton-Harris somewhere state that they mean something stronger by "irreducible representation" then the given statement is not correct (at least assuming AC). For an example, take any non-continuous automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$, and compose the determinant representation by this. The result is an irreducible representation not of the form specified.

Answer (score 1):

Finite dimensional representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, both as an algebraic group or as a complex Lie group are indexed by $n$-tuples $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq  \cdots \geq\lambda_n$.  Such a representation is polynomial if and only if $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq  \cdots \geq\lambda_n\geq 0$, in which case people often think of this as a partition.

As Tobias Kildetoft points out, you can do other crazy stuff if you don't require your representation to be continuous and holomorphic;  for example, $A \mapsto |\det(A)|^2$ is a representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a real Lie group or as a topological group, but it's not holomorphic, so it's not a representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a complex Lie group.